# Wordpress Dashboard visible but site is not after migration

Tags: errors, homepage, performance, installation, migration

I recently moved my WordPress site from Bluehost to Godaddy using Duplicator. I can access the site just fine if I am going to /wp-login or if I am in the dashboard. When I go to visit the website it does not load. Just a white background loads with no text. If I go to appearance and try to customize the theme I still see a white background.

I have tried the following

- Installing a new theme
- Reinstalling wordpress
- Activating different themes
- Repair & optimize Mysql database
- Reinstalling site using duplicator (problem persists)
- A different duplicator package (an older backup)

and I still am unable to view the site. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am getting the following error in my error log:

```
[07-Jul-2016 19:32:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tribe__Events__Venue' not found in /home6/poorric4/public_html/PR/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/Tribe/Main.php on line 769
```

**

Comment: Can you enable php errors and see what shows up?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook Yes, I added an edit with the error I am getting.

Comment: Reinstall that plugin in the admin as a first step in case it hasn't copied over properly.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook no luck. Maybe I do not have php errors enabled correctly... How should I enable that?

Comment: That error suggests you do. As it's fatal, php stops and hence the white page. Check your new host's php version and the plugin's minimum version. Something is stopping that class loading.

Comment: I currently have php 5.4 on bluehost I was running 5.3

Comment: And you have the latest versions of WP, plugin's and theme?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook Yes. Correct I do have all the latest plugins and themes. I have used this exact backup before on different webshots and it worked just fine.

Comment: I think you're going to have to try your new host and the plugin author. It looks like the problem may be a it too specific to fix without deeper knowledge of that plugin's needs. If it was my site and if the new hosting let me I'd try a fresh WP with just that plugin in it and see if that also fails. Then add other plugins and theme one by one to see what triggers it.

Comment: I have another site I can try to use the hosting on. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem - sorry I didn't get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin files need to be re uploaded. Could you please do the following: Backup `/home6/poorric4/public_html/PR/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/` delete `the-events-calendar` folder. Download the same version of events calendar from https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/developers/ (Do not upload the latest as there may be compatability issues)

Go to the backend and confirm the plugin is active.